# rails validate in model that value is inside array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation, text, model

I have a form where i pass a **field named** `:type` and i want to **check if it's value is inside an array of allowed types** so that **no one is allowed to post not-allowed types**.

the array looks like

```
@allowed_types = [
   'type1',
   'type2',
   'type3',
   'type4',
   'type5',
   'type6',
   'type7',
   etc...
]
```

i have **tried using** `validates_exclusion_of` or `validates_inclusion_of` but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

first,  change the attribute from type to something else,  type is a reserved attrubute name use for Single Table Inheritance and such.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :mytype, :inclusion=> { :in => @allowed_types }
```

Answer (score 23):

`ActiveModel::Validations` provides a helper method for this. An example call would be:

```
validates_inclusion_of :type, in: @allowed_types
```

ActiveRecord::Base is already a ActiveModel::Validations, so there is no need to include anything.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Also, @RadBrad is correct that you should not use `type` as a column name as it is reserved for STI.

Comment: While this works, it leads to a rubocop offence: RuboCop: Prefer the new style validations `validates :column, inclusion: value` over `validates_inclusion_of`. [Rails/Validation]

Comment: Potential edit: Rails now offers the ability to override the STI table via inheritance column.

Answer (score 16):

Just for those lazy people (like me) to copy the latest syntax:

```
validates :status, inclusion: %w[pending processing succeeded failed]
```

- `validates_inclusion_of` is out of date since Rails 3.
- `:inclusion=>` hash syntax is out of date since Ruby 2.0.
- In favor of `%w` for word array as the default [Rubocop option](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/WordArray).

With variations:

Default types as a constant:

```
STATUSES = %w[pending processing succeeded failed]

validates :status, inclusion: STATUSES
```

OP's original:

```
validates :mytype, inclusion: @allowed_types
```