# rails validate in model that value is inside array[2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation

This question similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059415/rails-validate-in-model-that-value-is-inside-array), but those answers don't work for me(May be they are deprecated). I don't want to reopen old question by bounty, because I have a little different arguments. In my case i have an array like this 
`allowed_values = [99.50..200]` and I tried with:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :price, :inclusion=> { :in => allowed_values }
```

It does not work. I have tried with so many ways by examples validation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). I have little experience on coding rails. So please, help to find solution.

**More info:**

```
       ruby version: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
       rails version: Rails 4.1.5
```

Comment: Does the `price` datatype is `Float/Integer`? If it is `String` it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be with the way you pass the `allowed_values` array.

You can go with this:

```
validates :price, inclusion: { in: (99.50..200) }
```

Or, with a constant:

```
ALLOWED_VALUES = (99.50..200).freeze
validates :price, inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_VALUES }
```

Comment: it does not work. does it depend on version of ruby or rails ?!

Comment: @Ulug'bekRo'zimboyev which version do you use? In which way is this not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Ulug'bekRo'zimboyev my question is still topical: which errors do you get?

Comment: it gives no error, why i say does not work, because if i set price=12, it says the model is valid. that's why I said it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

[99.50..200] is an array that contains a single element: the range (99.50..200).

You are testing whether the value is in the list of objects in the array, but what you probably want is to test whether it is in the range.

So define:

```
allowed_values = (99.50..200)
```

instead of:

```
allowed_values = [99.50..200]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: [How to implement min/max validator in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608423/1746258)

```
validates :price, :inclusion=> { :in => allowed_values }
```

does not work, it seems, validation style was changed after 3 version of rails. And I tried with:

```
validates_inclusion_of :number, :in => min_price..max_price
```

This solution has no valid case if `min_price=10.5 and max_price=11`

**My solution is:**

```
validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => min_price, :less_than_or_equal_to => :max_price }
```

I don't know ruby(and rails) deeply and I am not right some cases. but this solution is working